# How to check if one of the elements in an Array matches with another element?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a String Array called copy. I want to check if copy[0] matches with copy[2] and copy[3]. If it matches, then print something.

I tried using IF statements but i keep getting errors.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] copy = {"1","2","1","1","5","6","7","8","9"};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `equals` method:

```
if(copy[0].equals(copy[2]) && copy[0].equals(copy[3])) {
   System.out.printf("%s matches %s",copy[0], copy[1]);
}
```

if you use the equals operator == you are not comparing the values of the strings, as String is an object you should use the equals to compare the values.
The `==` operator checks if the two references are equals.

Comment: How to check if it equals three elements?